# how to generate samples with the given autocorrelation function

Tags: normal-distribution, autocorrelation, matlab, spatial, variogram

I want to generate some spatial data where the points/location in the space form a multivariate gaussian distribution. I want these points to have certain autocorrelation given by the variogram model like spherical with spill 0.025 and range 15. I then want to generate some sample for this

How can I do it?

I then want to plot the empirical variogram and again fit a model variogram to check if they come out to be similar. How can I do it?